# swagger shows attributes in a table as duplicate

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, swagger-ui

I tried to create a relational database. I wanted to add the id, email, password and telephone columns in the User table to the Employer and Employee tables. I created the structure as seen in the code below.

```
package hasancanozbek.hrms.Entities.concretes;

import hasancanozbek.hrms.Entities.abstracts.User;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "employers")
public class Employer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "company_website")
    private String companyWebsite;

    @Column(name = "verified")
    private boolean verified;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
   }
```

---

```
package hasancanozbek.hrms.Entities.abstracts;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import hasancanozbek.hrms.Entities.concretes.Employer;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "telephone")
    private String telephone;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JsonIgnore
    private Employer employer;
}
```

But when adding employer in swagger ui, each attribute is shown 2 times. For example, employers table has company name property, this property is displayed in swagger as both companyName and user.employer.companyName. I just want to combine and show the properties of the related table and additionally the properties from the user table. How can I fix?
[Swagger SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3iED.png)

Comment: In the screen everything seems fine, what the issue ? The `user.employer.companyName` is called a placeholder, and it will disappear when you will enter value

Comment: The problem is that I have to enter the company name 2 times. In fact, I just need to enter the company name field in the employer table. However, now I need to enter the same value twice for both the field in the employer table and the user.employer field.

Comment: Swagger is just a tester of web request, not a full website. So I don't understand why you need it

Comment: I know that. Anyway, my goal is to test before writing front-end. However, the problem is that I have to enter the same values twice as I mentioned above. Normally a company has a name, but as you can see in the picture, my code has both user.employer.companyName and employer.companyName. I added the @Jsonignore annotation but it still shows up. Actually I don't have a problem with swagger the problem is on the jpa side.

Comment: What library do you use to generate the API definition from code - Swagger Core, Springfox, something else?

Comment: I use swagger, spring boot, spring data, spring web, postgresql drivers for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I added to users table this anotation from *javax.persistence*.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

And I inherited Employer class from user class.
I added the following anotation under @Table on the line 15.

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

In this way, I have assigned the id value in the users table, which is my base table, to the user_id column of the tables connected to it. The name parameter is the column you will assign a value to, and the referencedColumName parameter is your primary key value in your base table.